# Damage reduction and Saint template

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage-reduction, character-templates

I'm currently speaking with the DM and another player, and we're having a disagreement. I'm looking at the Saint template, [listed here](http://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/templates/saint.shtml). The issue is that I'm being told that at Level 12+ the Saint would only acquire 10/evil and that's it. The reasoning is that these DRs *replace* each other, rather than being gained. I believe that a Saint should receive the 10/evil AND 5/magic.

My DM and the other player are quoting the last line in the damage reduction rules here:

> If a creature has damage reduction from more than one source, the two forms of damage reduction do not stack. Instead, the creature gets the benefit of the best damage reduction in a given situation.

My argument is that this does not support the given situation because this is about *same type bonuses* such as using two Rings of Fire Resistance to obtain an absurd level of resistance.

Which one of us is correct here?

Comment: Following the link, I see the Saint comes from "Book of Exalted Deeds" which presumably means the question is about dnd-3.5e.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a nitpick, but I'm not actually sure that a high-level saint has DR 5/magic at all.  Reading the table you linked, it seems to say that the DR 5/magic is applied to a saint that has HD between 4 and 7.  Once the saint's HD are higher than 7, the table seems to imply that the DR 5/magic actually goes away (replaced by DR 5/evil and later DR 10/evil).  This would be kind of a weird way for that power to work -- there are very few abilities in D&D that go away as you gain levels -- but it's something you might need to think about.

---

Let's assume the above nitpick is resolved.  A high-level saint can have both DR 10/evil and DR 5/magic, but it can't use both at once.  The saint gets "the benefit of the best damage reduction in a given situation."

If a high-level saint is attacked with a magic longsword, then the DR 5/magic won't help but the DR 10/evil will.  The best damage reduction in this situation is the DR 10/evil.  The saint ignores the first 10 points of damage.

If a high-level saint is attacked by an imp, then the best damage reduction in that situation is the DR 5/magic.  The saint ignores the first 5 points of damage.

If a high-level saint is hit by a falling rock, then the best damage reduction in that situation is the DR 10/evil.  The saint ignores the first 10 points of damage.  (*Not* the first fifteen.)

Comment: You could read that description as only applying at the moment the Saint template was gained, which would also be weird, but less weird than losing abilities.

Answer (score 2):

You have both, but they do not stack.

You benefit from whatever DR is the best, at the time of the damage. So you have a DR of 10/evil, unless that is bypassed* (in which case your DR is 5/magic).

- Note that in DR notation the text after the slash tells you what ignores the damage reduction ([link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/27884/2057)).